# Upload an image from device to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to use the code that `Firebase` documents provide and this is how much I have developed it. It just doesn't work. I have tried putting `Storage.storage().reference()` but it brings in more error to my code.

```
let downloadURL: String!

        if let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2){

            let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString

            let uploadTask = storage.reference().putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
              guard let metadata = metadata else {
                return
              }
                downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
```

The error I receive is `use of unidentified resolver storage`. But when I try `Storage.storage().reference()` it brings in 10 different error throughout my code.

Comment: I'll take what is I didn't import or installed pods correctly for $300? Lol jokes aside, did you install the right pods? If you need help with that, let me know. If thats not the case please post errors.

Comment: also I don't know if you didn't copy the full code but you're missing a couple `}`'s

Comment: Any update? I'd like to close this question out.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I see the question is receiving downvotes and it's like due to it being a bit unclear. Stating you're 'getting errors' and not indicating which line causes the error doesn't provide enough info for us to help. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know whats going on but, this works for me,

Make sure your pods has at least these in there.

**PODFILE**

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth' #Auth isn't needed but, you should really use it.
```

**View controller**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class TestView: UIViewController {
    var imageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView = UIImageView()

    }

    @IBAction func uploadPicture(_ sender: Any) {
        self.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "playlist.png")

        uploadMedia() { url in
             guard let url = url else { return }
            print(url)
        }

    }

    func uploadMedia(completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) {

       let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("something.png")
       if let uploadData = self.imageView.image?.pngData(){ //You can change this to jpeg, etc
           storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
               if error != nil {
                   print("error")
                   completion(nil)
               } else {

                   storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                       print(url?.absoluteString)
                       completion(url?.absoluteString)
                   })

               }
        }}}

}
```